# Disable select in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

On page is located HTML select list:

`<select ng-model="names" disabled="{{disabled}}" name="names" class="form-control input-medium">`

And in controller:

```
$scope.disabled = true;
```

And `ng-change`:

```
$scope.changeSpecialization = function (id){
    console.log(id); // Gives value more that 0
    if(id > 0){
      $scope.disabled = false;
    }
}
```

How you can see in method `changeSpecialization` I catch `id` and check it to zero. Console returns me value more that zero. So after is changed `$scope.disabled` to false. But on page select list is still disabled.

Comment: User angular directive 'ng-disabled' !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use [ngDisabled](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled) directive.

> This directive sets the disabled attribute on the element if the expression inside ngDisabled evaluates to truthy.

*Code Example*

```
<select ng-disabled="disabled" ng-model="names" name="names">
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you tell me, why when I use generated  select list in HTML, then angularjs resets selected option?

Comment: @chaps, You don't need to interpolate. Also notice `="disabled"` instead of `="{{disabled}}"`